# Is there a way I can make a loop with momentjs on minute change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to use momentjs to find even and odd minutes on the minute it changes.

I've read the momentjs docs and through some searching haven't found anything I can use or how I can apply it. Ultimately I want to use jquery to use addClass and removeClass to change the theme of the nav bar every minute instead of writing to console.

```
var now = new Date();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  if(minutes % 2 == 0){
    console.log('Time is even');
  } else {
    console.log("Time is odd");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you looking for [SetTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)?

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as a solution. Enjoy your stay at Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the the condition every 1s (1000ms) and get me odd/even value

```
setInterval(function() {
  let now = new Date();
  let minutes = now.getSeconds(); // You can change getSeconds() to getMinutes()
  if(minutes % 2 == 0) {
    console.log('Time is even');
  } else {
    console.log("Time is odd");
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This will get me going in the right direction.

Comment: setInterval runs until the code drops dead. If you need to be able to stop it for whatever reason you should hold on to the id that is returned from setInterval, then you can use cancelInterval(id).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setInterval` function to repeat some code in a specified interval. Example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  //This code gets executed every second(ish)
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  console.log(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
}, 1000);
```

In your case you would probably want to set the interval to 1000*60 to run your code every minute. Keep in mind that the setInterval function doesn't guarantee millisecond exact intervals but for most cases it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would rather need to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```
const intervalID = setInterval(function () {
   const minutes = now.getMinutes();
   if (minutes % 2 == 0) {
      console.log('Time is even');
   } else {
      console.log("Time is odd");
   }
}, 1000);
```